# Has Venom ever used the phrase “I am Venom” in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, venom, venom-2018

Venom’s phrase “**We are Venom**” is something unforgettable, especially after the new Venom movie.

In the ***Venom (2018)*** movie, when Eddie has his first conversation with the symbiote,

> Eddie: Who *are* you?
>
> Venom: ***I am Venom***, and you are mine.

In the comics, has the Venom symbiote (with and/or without its host) ever addressed himself/itself as “**I**” and not “**WE**”?

Comment: “Venom’s phrase “We are Venom” is something unforgettable, especially after the new Venom movie” — ironic, as everyone involved in the movie is now desperately trying to forget it.

Comment: Also is this strictly about the Venom symbiote? Because I can think of at least one other symbiote referring to the duo as "I" ("I am the ultimate insanity! I am Carnage!", _Maximum Carnage_ #1, 1994). Granted though, Carnage has a whole other psychology than Venom...

Comment: @Jenayah I too remember Carnage addressing himself as I (from Spider-Man the animated series). I was looking for Venom specifically.

Comment: On a side note, I restricted my answer below as to only "I am Venom" occurences; it turns out Venom uses the first person a whole lot more than one would imagine.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, on at least three occasions.

---

Know what happens when a character who is most known for only saying "I am Groot" gets Venomized? Well, *Guardians of the Galaxy* #21 (2014) has your answer.

He says "I am Venom".

[image: Groot is Venomized]

Another time was in *Venom: Along came a Spider* #1 (1996). Eddie Brock disguises himself as detective Clark from the NYPD (using the Symbiote), and drops the mask, revealing himself as "I'm Venom".

> **Clark/Eddie:** Don't pull down on the little twerp - he's not Venom!
>  
>   **Steen:** How do you know, Clark?
>   **Eddie:** Because I'm Venom!

[image: Because I'm Venom]

As far as I know, the first time the "I'm Venom" phrasing was used was in 1993, in *Venom: The Madness* #2. After agreeing to bond with the "living mercury" contained in a pool Juggernaut had thrown him in (what? It doesn't sound like a reasonable idea to you?), Venom got some kind of an upgrade and sought out an innocent to save, introducing itself as "I'm Venom".

Granted, in this case the "I'm Venom" wording instead of the usual "We are Venom" might be due to the demons playing with his mind through the living mercury.

[image: Hello, Kitty. I'm Venom. Do you need saving today?]

Comment: Man... I never got into reading comics, but that is *awesome*.

Comment: So in the recent film this venom is actually Groot/venom? Interesting....

Comment: @LioElbammalf - No, this was a short-term thing; Venom was temporarily separated from his host at the time, and they were reunited by the end of the storyline.

Comment: Poor kitty but anyways +1